# Aspose.pdf returns white pages

Tags: pdf, aspose, aspose.pdf

i'm trying to generate a pdf from some input data.
So I created my PdfGenerator() and that creates a pdf with some text:

```
public class PdfGenerator {

    public PdfGenerator() {
        //Instantiate License class and call its SetLicense method to use the license
        var license = new Aspose.Pdf.License();
        license.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");
    }

    public void Generate(Generation input) {
        //Create pdf document
        var pdf1 = new Pdf();

        //Add a section into the pdf document
        var sec1 = pdf1.Sections.Add();

        //Add a text paragraph into the section
        sec1.Paragraphs.Add(new Text("Hello World"));

        //Save the document
        pdf1.Save(input.Reference + ".pdf", SaveType.OpenInBrowser, HttpContext.Current.Response);
    }
}
```

this is being called from my HttpPost method:

```
    // POST api/values
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]Generation value) {
        _pdfGenerator.Generate(value);
    }
```

but I only get a white paged pdf, any idea why I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't the .Net code, it was on my client, I needed to add:

```
{responseType:'arraybuffer'}
```

on my http request (javascript)